# Pygame compile() expected string without null bytes

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pygame

So I'm new to pygame and I'm trying to compile the simplest program I can think of, to open a window. However, I tried two different compiling methods I found on the internet and both of them give me this:

```
error: compiling 'C:\Python27\lib\email\parser.py' failed
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
```

I also found a thread on here that suggested import json and I tried that and it still didn't work.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import pygame, sys
import json
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

I tried to use the code I found here:
http://pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe?parent=

and here: http://pythoncentral.io/py2exe-python-to-exe-introduction/

What's happening here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

welcome to stackoverflow. You had made a slight typo in your code in the DISPLAYSURF.
Instead of

```
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
```

You have to add brackets around 400 and 300 to make it a tuple.

```
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode([400,300])
```

However I can't help with your compiling I will need more information and code. It may not be compiling due to this typo

Comment: It seems to work fine regardless of using parentheses or brackets, but I tried compiling it with brackets and it came up with the same error. This is really all the information I have. Thank you, though.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can assign the values of screen size and width before.
Like,

```
display_width = 1080
display_height  = 720
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
```

This will work perfectly.